# awk: run time error: negative field index

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I currently have the following:

```
function abs() {
    echo $(($1<0 ?-$1:$1));
}

echo $var1 | awk -F" " '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i+=2) $i=(95-$(abs $i))*1.667}'
```

where `var1` is:

```
4 -38 2 -42 1 -43 10 -44 1 -45 6 -46 1 -48 1 -49
```

When I run this, I am getting the error:

```
awk: run time error: negative field index $-38
FILENAME="-" FNR=1 NR=1
```

Does this have something to do with the `95-$(abs $i)` part? I'm not sure how to fix this.

Comment: Bash functions can't be accessed inside Awk as it's a separate language with it's own interpreter.

Comment: ... and therefore `$(abs $i)` first computes the string concatenation of `abs` and `$i`, which is the same as the value of `$i` because `abs` hasn't been defined in awk and is therefore the empty string, and then uses the result as a field number, just as though you'd written `$$i`. When `i` is `2`, that is `$-38`; hence the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo "$var1" |
awk 'function abs(x) { return x<0 ? -x : x }
     { for (i=2;i<=NF;i+=2) $i = (95-abs($i))*1.667; print }'
```

Answer (score 0):

Every line of input to AWK is placed in fields by the interpreter. The fields can be accessed with $N for N > 0. $0 means the whole line. $N for N < 0 is nonsensical. Variables are not prefixed with a dollar sign.